# iOS 9 Background Location update and Update on server using web-service

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, background-process, location-services

I have developed an application that has the capability to update the location on server while application is in background as well as foreground. I have used Timer which continuously updates location with 1 minute time interval, because if the interval is more than 1 minute , `iOS` suspends the application in background.

The problem is with iOS 9, when application is in background, some time it stops the location update and after some random time duration it again starts.

These are the crash logs which I found from device logs.

```
Exception Type:  00000020
    Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
    Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
    Highlighted by Thread:  2

    Application Specific Information:
    <BKNewProcess: 0x15646220; com.com.com; pid: 1168; hostpid: -1> has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
    {(
        <BKProcessAssertion: 0x15537b80> id: 1168-1B744B09-0EB7-4B01-A6FE-F167669E4439 name: Called by UIKit, from <redacted> process: <BKNewProcess: 0x15646220; com.com.com; pid: 1168; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:1168 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep ,
        <BKProcessAssertion: 0x15643480> id: 1168-59515322-D982-46F8-94A5-0DD259406664 name: Called by UIKit, from <redacted> process: <BKNewProcess: 0x15646220; com.com.com; pid: 1168; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:1168 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
    )}
    Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 6.880 (user 6.880, system 0.000), 9% CPU 
    Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.081, 0% CPU
```

Note: Everything is working completely fine in iOS 7 and iOS 8.

I have tried couple of solutions available on stackoverflow but I am not able to figure out the exact solutions which can solve the problem.

Also I found that if I don't lock the device then the location update and web-service calling works fine but if the device is locked, it stops updating location and calling up web-service.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

`AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *currentLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* locationUpdateTimer;
-(void)updateUsersLocation;
-(void)distroyTimer;
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
-(void)callLocationManager
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        UIAlertView * alert;
        //We have to make sure that the Background App Refresh is enable for the Location updates to work in the background.
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied)
        {
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:ALERTTITLE
                                              message:@"The app doesn't work without the Background App Refresh enabled. To turn it on, go to Settings > General > Background App Refresh"
                                             delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
        }
        else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted)
        {
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:ALERTTITLE
                                              message:@"The functions of this app are limited because the Background App Refresh is disable."
                                             delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
        }
        else if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@""
                                  message:@"Please enable GPS service for HiHo Mobile From settings"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!self.locationManager)
            {
                self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            }
            self.locationManager.delegate = self;
            // self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;
            self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;

            if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
            {
                [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }

            if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)])
            {
                self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates  = YES;
            }
            if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)])
            {
                self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically= NO;
            }
            if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)])
            {
                [self.locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
            }
            [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

            if ([USERDEFAULTS boolForKey:@"someFlag"]==YES)
            {
                [self distroyTimer];
                self.locationUpdateTimer =
                [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:180
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(updateUsersLocation)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
                [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]addTimer:self.locationUpdateTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
            }
            else
            {
                [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
                [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)distroyTimer
{
    if ([self.locationUpdateTimer isValid])
    {
        [self.locationUpdateTimer invalidate];
        self.locationUpdateTimer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"latitude: %f, longitude: %f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
}
```

// Write your code to update location on server

```
-(void)updateUsersLocation
{
    // Your code goes here.
}
```

Note: Continuous update of location services will dramatically drain your iOS device's battery. So as soon as you have no use of updated location you can use `significant locations`.

Comment: This seems too similar to an Issue I was having, by any chance do you use localytics?

Comment: No, we are not using any localytics. We are tracing location update with our own backend and using device `NSLog()`

Comment: @quant24 how did you resolve the issue with Localytics?  What was the problem?

Comment: @VatsalK I am working on same kind of project. Can you provide sample code?

Comment: @venky I have removed timers for stoping and starting again locationmanager update. Then it won't suspend the application and you will background location updates for longer time.

Comment: @VatsalK Are you able to send data to server without use of timer and backgroundtask? I need to send a location update to server every 20 sec even app is in background

Comment: @venky Well, I have used timer for this but you can add some timing logic with `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` method using timestemp and get difference of every 20 seconds.

Comment: @venky I have updated question with working source code, I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have kept a timer for starting and stopping the location manager, as I have posted a same question to apple developers and they suggest me to keep a single location manager for application and **remove the timers** which might gets **affected during threads while application works in background**, so finally I have **removed the timers logic**, and now location manager continuously updates the location until the user gets logged out. This might drain the battery but this one is the only solutions that I found and which is working for our application.

Comment: For expressing your gratitude, you have the upvote button :) No explicit thanks is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Location updates Background mode to get the location updates in background then you app will wakeup from background when ever didupdalocation is called Please see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for better understanding .

Comment: I have already updated this things and kept
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>fetch</string>
  <string>location</string>
 </array>
Also for iOS 9 we have added
<key>allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates</key>
 <string>YES</string>

so it will allow us to update the location in background as well.

Comment: can you post Your location update code and upload code?

Comment: I have used [this classes](https://github.com/voyage11/Location) for updating the location.
And a timer is set for updating the location on server.
self.locationUpdateTimer =
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kPingFrequencyTime
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(updateLocation)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

The new **allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates** can't stay at plist, you must put it in code.

```
myLM = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if([myLM respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)]) {
   [myLM setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates: YES];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have added this condition along with pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically. 
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)])
            {
                self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates  = YES;
            }
            if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)])
            {
                self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically= NO;
            }

Comment: @VatsalK Are you requesting user authorization with **requestAlwaysAuthorization**? Do you start the location manager while the app still in foreground?  Can you post how you create, configure and initialize the localion manager? Also be sure that you are not stopping it anywhere!

Comment: Yep, I am using **requestAlwaysAuthorization**. As everything is working fine in Foreground mode and I am not stopping the location manager until it is suppose to be.